# binary executable in java android permission denied

Tags: java, selinux, busybox

I'm trying to use busybox in my non-rooted application but for some reason I'm getting a permission denied error, I'm testing on Android 11 and I gave all permissions to the executable like 'chmod 777' but the executable still doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxinA.jpg)

Esse é meu código pra executar comando

```
Process mProcess = mProcessBuilder.start();
            
            BufferedReader mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mProcess.getInputStream()));
            
            String line = null;
            while ((line = mBufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                publishProgress(String.format("%s\n", line));
            }
            mBufferedReader.close();
            
            BufferedReader mBufferedReaderError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mProcess.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = mBufferedReaderError.readLine()) != null) {
                publishProgress(String.format("%s\n", line));
            }
            mBufferedReaderError.close();
            
            mProcess.waitFor();
```